# Gorm bulk upsert duplicated association returning `cannot affect row a second time`

Tags: go, associations, grails-orm

I have the following gorm models

```golang
type Access struct {
  ID       string
  User     string
  Resource *Resource
}

type Resource struct {
  ID  string
  URN string
}
```

and the following data that I want to (bulk) upsert into the db

```golang
data := []*Access{
  {User: "user1", Resource: &Resource{URN: "resource1"}},
  {User: "user2", Resource: &Resource{URN: "resource1"}},
  {User: "user3", Resource: &Resource{URN: "resource1"}},
  {User: "user4", Resource: &Resource{URN: "resource1"}},
}

db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{UpdateAll: true}).Create(data)
```

the generated query for inserting the `Resource`s is like this:

```
INSERT INTO "resources" ("urn") VALUES ("resource1"), ("resource1"), ("resource1"), ("resource1")
ON CONFLICT ("urn") DO UPDATE SET "updated_at"="excluded"."updated_at" RETURNING "id"
```

and it is returning an error:

```
ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time (SQLSTATE 21000)
```

I think it's because of the resource insertion it inserted duplicated resources and the `ON CONFLICT` couldn't handle it. If that's the case, how can I make gorm deduplicate the resources first?

I'm using gorm v1.24.3